# diff-invariant, regulator, cutoff integral on string theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

The diff-invariant distance between $z'$ and $z$ is (for short distances) $e^{w(z)}|z'-z|$, so a diff-invaraint cutoff would be at $|z'-z|=\epsilon e^{-w(z)}$. Then

$$
  \int d^{2}z'\frac{1}{|z'-z|^{2}} \sim -2\pi \ln(\epsilon e^{-w(z)}) 
$$

How can i derive this equation?

Also here we are dealing with complex variable $z$ and $z'$. So the integral is done
over complex plane, and 'diff-invariant' means 'diffeomorphism-invariant'.

Comment: I could probably guess it, but what are $z$ and $z'$? Is 'diff-invariant' = 'diffeomorphism-invariant'? Is the integral over a plane? How is the cutoff implemented?

Comment: This integral is related in one of Polchinski's exercises which i couldn't fully understand.